# Equinumerousity for prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was reading about  [Modular Prime Counting Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularPrimeCountingFunction.html) where for counting of primes a notion of **equinumerousity** was introduced.

What does this notion mean exactly  - is it equivalent, for example in the context of counting primes of the form $3k+1$ and $3k+2$, to the following formula 
 $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{\pi_{3,1}(n)}{\pi_{3,2}(n)}=1$?

Additionally:
are primes numbers always equinumerous in partitions of $\mathbb{Z^+}$ corresponding to the numbers represented by the form $pk+ p_i$? ($p_i= 1,2,3, \dots, p-1 $, of course for such partition $p_i$ only where they are occurring).

Comment: It looks like it means as in your post.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#Distribution

Comment: @MichaelStocker so it seems that so called Euler's totient function describes the partitions..

Comment: It does indeed :)